# Populate multiple lists from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

There are *similar* questions already on here, but none of them quite suit my situation. Basically, I want to populate a variable number of select menus with the same data from a MYSQL database. The reason for this is that I would like the user to be able to add rows to submit multiple choices simultaneously.

In order to avoid doing a login --> read of MYSQL for each instance of the select menu, I created an array which would be used to populate the menu whenever necessary. The problem is that it works ONLY for the first instance; in other words, PHP is somehow deleting the values stored in the array after the first reading.

I apologise if this question is very basic, I am quite new to PHP.

Here is my code so far:

TO ACCESS MYSQL AND DEFINE VARIABLE 'result':

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sonch_PUBLIC";
    $password = "sonch_PUBLIC";
    $dbname = "sonch_MAIN";
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

    //START SEARCH BY VENUE
    $sql = "SELECT Name, City FROM Venue ORDER BY City";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

TO POPULATE THE FIRST INSTANCE OF :

```
<select style="width:138px; text-align:center">
    <option selected>CHOOSE VENUE</option>';
    <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option>" . $row["Name"] . " - " . $row["City"] . "</option>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

So far so good.... but when I want to populate subsequent  menus with the same code, i.e., by repeating:

```
<select style="width:138px; text-align:center">
    <option selected>CHOOSE VENUE</option>';
    <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option>" . $row["Name"] . " - " . $row["City"] . "</option>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

...they are empty.

Suggestions?

Comment: The page in question is: http://www.s-on.ch/add2-event.php .... you can see that the 'choose venue' option is populated in the first instance, but when a new line is added, the menu is empty.

Comment: You are NOT creating an array to be used many times. You are just processing a result set. Once you consume the resultset it is finished. Do as you suggested yourself and process the resultset into an array and then reuse the array

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought that I had set 'result' as an array..... could you please show me how to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT creating an array to be used many times. You are just processing a result set. Once you consume the resultset it is finished. Do as you suggested yourself and process the resultset into an array and then reuse the array

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "sonch_PUBLIC";
    $password = "sonch_PUBLIC";
    $dbname = "sonch_MAIN";
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

    //START SEARCH BY VENUE
    $sql = "SELECT Name, City FROM Venue ORDER BY City";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // If you have the MySQL Native Driver installed
    //$allRows = $result->fetch_all();

    // if you dont have the MySQL Native Driver installed you will have to do this
    $allRows = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $allRows[] = $row;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

FIRST INSTANCE

```
<select style="width:138px; text-align:center">
<option selected>CHOOSE VENUE</option>';
<?php
    foreach ($allRows as $row) {
        echo "<option>" . $row["Name"] . " - " . $row["City"] . "</option>";
    } 
?>
</select>
```

And as many times as you like reuse that array

Comment: I apologise, I am obviously doing something stupid here..... when I add the code, the page no longer displays (<body></body> =$0 in console).....

Comment: It all works if I remove 'fetch_all()' from the code you gave me.... but I don't feel good about just blindly hacking into code until it does what i want it to...

Comment: That makes no sense. If you remove the `fetch_all()` then the array will be empty and there will be no data to output.... Hmmmm the plot thickens

Comment: Ahh I bet I know what it is.... Your system does not have the MySQL Native Driver installed. So `fetch_all()` will not work. Two secs I will amend accordingly

Comment: Ok try that foreach loop to unload the resultset and create the array

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please clarify?

Comment: THere are 2 bits of code that can be installed to make PHP and MySQL talk together. If you use the other, cannot remember what to call it, there is no `fetch_all()` function available to use. If you have the MySQL Native Driver, that contains the `fetch_all()` function

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Does it run using the second approach?

Comment: Still working on it, but I think that you are correct and that this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your first `while` loop:

```
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option>" . $row["Name"] . " - " . $row["City"] . "</option>";
        }
```

reads all the data from the result set. So when you do the second one, there is nothing left to read. To fix that, you need to reset the data pointer using [`mysqli::data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php). So before the subsequent `while` loops, add this line:

```
 $result->data_seek(0);
```

`data_seek` moves the result set read pointer to the specified row number. In this case, we are moving it back to row 0, or the start of the result set. Having done that, you can then read the result set again in full

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. I have to admit that I do not completely understand why though. I understand that the data was being read and could not be read again, but how does this line change that exactly?

Comment: `data_seek` moves the result set read pointer to the specified row number. In this case, we are moving it back to row 0, or the start of the result set. Having done that, you can then read the result set again in full.